# Foreign characters not showing on Chrome, using Arch Linux (Anarchy)

Tags: chrome, language

I have been using Anarchy and have Chrome installed. Everything is great except for when I try and view pages with foreign characters in particular Duolingo.com for learning Chinese the characters don't show.

I am aware that I probably need to download a language pack or two but can't seem to find out how after Googling the issue.

Comment: First check (e.g. in a terminal or some other graphics program displaying text) that the offending glyphs really do show elsewhere. It might not be chrome's fault...

Comment: Please link directly to a page which shows the problem and copy/paste into your question text some of the text that isn't displaying properly.